# Maven copy dependencies of dependency

Tags: java, maven, jar, copy, dependencies

I'm having troubles with Maven.

Let's say I have some Java (Maven) projects:

- X
- Y

I would like to include project Y in project X as a dependency.
However, I want to copy all "lib" dependencies of Y project as well.

Has anybody any idea ?

Comment: Fixed some grammar and some formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IF** project X and Y are Maven projects you will just need a dependency to porject Y from within your project X's `pom.xml`. One of Maven's key features is that there is normally no need to copy any libraries of other Maven projects you are having dependencies to - Maven will resolve the required dependencies of your (direct) dependency (in your example based on the dependency-definitions in the `pom.xml` of project Y) and deliver those to project X as well.

Those "dependencies of my dependencies" are called transitive dependencies and are well described in the official documentation: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

I would however recomend to quickly overfly/ read the entire documentation starting at http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html to understand the key concept since it differs quite a lot to the "old way of handling library management".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

via cmd/terminal? If you have Y already defined as dependency in the pom.xml, the dependent dependencies of Y are also fetched.

But of course then they are just in the ~/.m2/repository Folder. To get them directly to your project, you should have a look at the Assembly plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html